# Borrowed value does not live long enough when using functions with lifetime specifier

Tags: rust, compiler-errors, lifetime

I am fairly unfamiliar with Rust lifetime. Here is the code I wrote:

```
pub fn from_reader<'de, T, R>(reader: &'de mut R) -> Result<T>
where
    T: Deserialize<'de>,
    R: Read,
{
    let mut reader = BufReader::new(reader);
    from_buf_reader(&mut reader)
}

pub fn from_buf_reader<'de, T, R>(reader: &'de mut R) -> Result<T>
where
    T: Deserialize<'de>,
    R: BufRead,
{
    //...
}
```

I got the following error:

```
error[E0597]: `reader` does not live long enough
  --> src/de.rs:34:21
   |
28 | pub fn from_reader<'de, T, R>(reader: &'de mut R) -> Result<T>
   |                    --- lifetime `'de` defined here
...
34 |     from_buf_reader(&mut reader)
   |     ----------------^^^^^^^^^^^-
   |     |               |
   |     |               borrowed value does not live long enough
   |     argument requires that `reader` is borrowed for `'de`
35 | }
   | - `reader` dropped here while still borrowed
```

From my understanding, the newly created `reader` needs to have `'de` lifetime, which is not possible because `'de` begins before this function is even called. Is this the correct interpretation?

Is there a way around this issue without directly taking ownership of the parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general principle, it is *almost always a mistake* to use the same lifetime parameter for an `&mut` reference as anything else. This is because the lifetime of a mutable reference is *invariant:* unlike an immutable reference, you can't label it with a lifetime that is *shorter* than the actual lifetime of the original borrow (as this would interfere with verifying that there is no overlap of mutable borrows with any other).

However, you don't need that principle as there's a much more straightforward problem here:

In Serde, `Deserialize<'de>` means "deserialize into a structure which *borrows from data with the lifetime `'de`.*"

1. The result of deserialization is only valid for the lifetime `'de`.
2. The deserialization takes input which must live for the lifetime `'de`.

That input which must live is not `reader`; it is the *bytes that are read.* You cannot use a lifetime that predates the bytes actually getting read.

If you're trying to perform zero-copy deserialization, you must read the bytes into a buffer and *keep them around until you're done with the value.*

If you just want a function with approximately the signature you have, then use `DeserializeOwned` instead of `Deserialize<'de>` — that requires the deserialized value to not borrow from the input, so its lifetime is independent of the input.